# Creating a form which allows you to pick which sheets you want to run a macro in

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've got some system extracts which contains several dozens of sheets in identical formats. In order to better present the data from each sheet, I like to create simple summary tables for a number of (not all) sheets.

I've created a simple macro which extracts the key data from the sheet into a table. What I'd like is if I could select which sheets I want to run the macro on, for example by using checkboxes on a form. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Make the macro a subroutine that accepts a string argument that is the sheet name, and then make the sheet name a variable in the code. Then it's just a matter of using a multiselect listbox.

Answer (score 0):

### You can incorporate [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that will fire on selection of each checkbox.

You can retrieve the cell in which the checkbox has been checked with [`e.range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) and proceed accordingly to your needs.

**Sample:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var checkboxColumnIndex=1: //as a sample
  //if the edited cell is your checkbox column and the box status was changed from unchecked to checked
  if(e.range.getColumn()==checkboxColumnIndex2&&e.range.getValue()==true){
   var checkboxRow=e.range.getRow());
   var sheetIndex=checkBoxRow();
   var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[sheetIndex];
  //do what you wnat with this sheet
  }
}
```

This function will run automatically each time a checkbox has been checked.